# Add Conditons to Unhide column in a sheet with Mulitple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

A little Help again please.
Codes below work for hiding columns that do not match B5.
Now my problem is, I want to unhide column that matches values 
from B6 and B7 at the same time.
Reference Values from Command Sheet Column B Row 5,6,7.
Let B5 is MARCH
Let B6 is JANUARY[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ5fH.jpg)
Let B7 is FEBRUARY
Sheet Name (GRA_NewGen CI) Note that All Data's per row/column are here.
Range from Sheet Name to Match B5,B6,B7 is Column C Row 4 up to End of Column in row with Values.

Below is the 'Code

```
'Sub GRA_NewGen_CI()
Dim cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("GRA_New Gen CI")
  For Each cell In .Range("C4", .Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft))
     cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value <> Sheets("Command").Range("B5") And Not IsEmpty(cell)
  Next cell
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
'End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to hide all rows marked "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY" etc. you will have more flexibility and faster action by using Excel's Filter functionality. Learn [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/filter.html) about Filters.

Comment: @ Variatus Hello, Thank you for sharing.. but what we want to unhide all columns that matches "January" And February". "January and February are headers of the column.. which can be found in a single row(Col C Row 4). =)

Answer (score 0):

That gave me quite a ride. All those hidden columns are tricky. But now it's your turn. Please follow the instructions.

On your 'Command' sheet, find a blank column and enter "Show All" in one of the cells and this function in the cell below that:

```
="Show "& B5
```

I prefer you to have all the 12 months in B5:B16, but if you have only Jan to Mar or prefer to change the content on the fly that is OK as well. Copy the formula down for as long as you have relevant data (month names or column captions) in column B. Give the range I just described a name. I gave it the name "DropdownList". Make sure the named range has a 'Scope' of "Workbook" (meaning, it is visible from all parts of the workbook).

Place a command button on the GRA_New sheet in position A4. Perhaps you already have a button elsewhere. In that case I will ask you to play along and make another one for now. Later you can move this button to any other location, including another sheet, but not in a column to be possibly hidden. This command button will be a Validation drop-down. Enter

```
"Allow" = List and 
"Source" =DropdownList (including the = mark.
```

You should now have a validation dropdown showing "Show All" in first position, "Show January" in second, and more "Show ..." depending upon the size of the named range DropdownList. Make sure that there is a single space between in "Show January" and "Show all", not more and not less, and every line consisting of 2 words, the second of which is relevant.

Now add the following procedure to the code sheet of the "GR_New ..." sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '17 Mar 2017
    If Target.Address = Range("A4").Address Then
        SetDisplay_GRA_NewGen Split(Target.Value)(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

In this procedure, please change the reference to "A4" to the cell where you have the validation dropdown.

The next procedure goes into a normal code module. By default its name would be "Module1", but you can give it any name you like.

```
Sub SetDisplay_GRA_NewGen(ByVal Cmd As String)
    ' 17 Mar 2017

    Dim Spike As String
    Dim CountHidden As Integer
    Dim FirstColumn As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim CapRow As Long, Cap As String
    Dim C As Long

    CapRow = 4
    FirstColumn = 3                     ' = column C

    With Worksheets("GRA_New_Gen_CI")
        LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If StrComp(Cmd, "all", vbTextCompare) Then
            With Range("DropdownList")
                For C = 2 To .Rows.Count
                    Cap = Split(.Cells(C).Value)(1)
                    Spike = Spike & "|" & Cap
                Next C
            End With

            For C = FirstColumn To LastColumn           ' count hidden columns
                Cap = .Cells(CapRow, C).Value
                If .Columns(C).Hidden Then
                    If .Columns(C).Hidden Or InStr(1, Spike, Cap, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        ' if Cap can't be selected it is counted as not hidden
                        CountHidden = CountHidden + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next C

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            If CountHidden = 0 Then
                ' hide all except the specified column
                .Range(.Columns(FirstColumn), .Columns(LastColumn)).Hidden = True
            End If

            For C = FirstColumn To LastColumn
                With .Columns(C)
                    If .Hidden Then
                        Cap = .Cells(CapRow).Value
                        If StrComp(Cap, Cmd, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .Hidden = False
                    End If
                End With
            Next C
        Else
            .Range(.Columns(FirstColumn), .Columns(LastColumn)).Hidden = False
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Look for the two declarations in this procedure:

```
CapRow = 4
FirstColumn = 3
```

Row 4 is the row on your data sheet in which the program will look for the months names. Column 3 (= "C") will be the first column in which the program will expect to find a month's name. Columns A:B will never be touched.

Now your system is ready. You will need to know how to operate it.
1. When you select "Show All" from the dropdown all columns starting from FirstColumn will be shown. Call this a reset.
2. When you select any of the items from the dropdown columns with that name in CapRow will be shown.
3. When you select another month it will be added to the one already shown.
4. When all columns are shown already, only the selected one will be displayed.

You can modify the range DropdownList anytime, make it longer or shorter. The important thing is that the names in the dropdown are available in the CapRow. The program compares them as text, meaning "show all" is the same as "SHOW ALL".